# In-floor heat disconnect

Tags: heating

I am removing my hot water tank for the in-floor heat. There is no longer a water supply to it and it is being disconnected. Is there anything else I need to do in case in the future someone wants to install a different heating unit for the in-floor?

Comment: @FreeMan  I'd like to think whoever is doing the work would know to cap off the feed and return lines.  Next to the OP: ...with proper drainage and connections, they should blow out the system with a compressor to remove as much water as possible. Depending upon the design/layout of the infloor heat, it may require quite some time opening and closing valves to get as much water out as possible.    BTW, this is just a question: Why are you abandoning in-floor heat? I have it and love it.  What are you going to substitute it with?

Comment: The way this in-floor heat system was installed was with one zone for the entire house which sits on a slab. We have a heat pump now and although the floor is cool on the feet, it has proven to be much more efficient. We also have small baseboard heaters as a backup in extremely cold weather. The in- floor was also very expensive to run and we haven`t had it on in eight years. I want to remove the water tank before it starts to leak.

Answer (score 1):

Vacuum (wet vac) and/or blow fluid out of the tubing.  *Use limited pressure and don't overpressurize the tubing and rupture it*. Seal (plug) the ends.

**LABEL EVERYTHING.**

The biggest hazard to unused installed in-floor heating is someone coming along and saying - *"What are these unused pipes sticking out here?"* and chopping them off. If you have such a thing, print out a complete system diagram and put it in a sealed plastic bag taped to the pipes. Put a second copy on the wall, if there's wall handy.